# I can't install extension python for vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

Before 19.06.2020 this extension worked successfully, but now it isn't.
Previous version of extension worked, VSCode tried to install new version and something goes wrong. New version number is below.
Extension version: v2020.6.89148
VSCode version : version 1.46
OS:
Description:    Manjaro Linux
Release:        20.0.1
Codename:       Lysia

Extension logs

```
[2020-06-19 17:07:47.140] [exthost] [info] extension host started
[2020-06-19 17:07:47.238] [exthost] [info] ExtensionService#_doActivateExtension vscode.debug-auto-launch {"startup":true,"extensionId":{"value":"vscode.debug-auto-launch","_lower":"vscode.debug-auto-launch"},"activationEvent":"*"}
[2020-06-19 17:07:47.245] [exthost] [info] ExtensionService#loadCommonJSModule file:///var/lib/snapd/snap/code/35/usr/share/code/resources/app/extensions/debug-auto-launch/dist/extension
[2020-06-19 17:07:47.270] [exthost] [info] ExtensionService#_doActivateExtension vscode.emmet {"startup":true,"extensionId":{"value":"vscode.emmet","_lower":"vscode.emmet"},"activationEvent":"*"}
[2020-06-19 17:07:47.270] [exthost] [info] ExtensionService#loadCommonJSModule file:///var/lib/snapd/snap/code/35/usr/share/code/resources/app/extensions/emmet/dist/extension
[2020-06-19 17:07:47.348] [exthost] [info] ExtensionService#_doActivateExtension vscode.git {"startup":true,"extensionId":{"value":"vscode.github","_lower":"vscode.github"},"activationEvent":"*"}
[2020-06-19 17:07:47.348] [exthost] [info] ExtensionService#loadCommonJSModule file:///var/lib/snapd/snap/code/35/usr/share/code/resources/app/extensions/git/dist/main
[2020-06-19 17:07:47.494] [exthost] [info] ExtensionService#_doActivateExtension vscode.github-authentication {"startup":true,"extensionId":{"value":"vscode.github-authentication","_lower":"vscode.github-authentication"},"activationEvent":"*"}
[2020-06-19 17:07:47.495] [exthost] [info] ExtensionService#loadCommonJSModule file:///var/lib/snapd/snap/code/35/usr/share/code/resources/app/extensions/github-authentication/dist/extension.js
[2020-06-19 17:07:47.522] [exthost] [info] ExtensionService#_doActivateExtension vscode.merge-conflict {"startup":true,"extensionId":{"value":"vscode.merge-conflict","_lower":"vscode.merge-conflict"},"activationEvent":"*"}
[2020-06-19 17:07:47.523] [exthost] [info] ExtensionService#loadCommonJSModule file:///var/lib/snapd/snap/code/35/usr/share/code/resources/app/extensions/merge-conflict/dist/extension
[2020-06-19 17:07:47.536] [exthost] [info] ExtensionService#_doActivateExtension vscode.microsoft-authentication {"startup":true,"extensionId":{"value":"vscode.microsoft-authentication","_lower":"vscode.microsoft-authentication"},"activationEvent":"*"}
[2020-06-19 17:07:47.536] [exthost] [info] ExtensionService#loadCommonJSModule file:///var/lib/snapd/snap/code/35/usr/share/code/resources/app/extensions/microsoft-authentication/dist/extension.js
[2020-06-19 17:07:47.563] [exthost] [info] ExtensionService#_doActivateExtension vscode.search-result {"startup":true,"extensionId":{"value":"vscode.search-result","_lower":"vscode.search-result"},"activationEvent":"*"}
[2020-06-19 17:07:47.564] [exthost] [info] ExtensionService#loadCommonJSModule file:///var/lib/snapd/snap/code/35/usr/share/code/resources/app/extensions/search-result/dist/extension.js
[2020-06-19 17:07:47.566] [exthost] [info] ExtensionService#_doActivateExtension Equinusocio.vsc-material-theme {"startup":true,"extensionId":{"value":"Equinusocio.vsc-material-theme","_lower":"equinusocio.vsc-material-theme"},"activationEvent":"*"}
[2020-06-19 17:07:47.567] [exthost] [info] ExtensionService#loadCommonJSModule file:///home/ian/.vscode/extensions/equinusocio.vsc-material-theme-32.6.0/build/material.theme.config
[2020-06-19 17:07:47.578] [exthost] [info] ExtensionService#_doActivateExtension equinusocio.vsc-material-theme-icons {"startup":true,"extensionId":{"value":"equinusocio.vsc-material-theme-icons","_lower":"equinusocio.vsc-material-theme-icons"},"activationEvent":"*"}
[2020-06-19 17:07:47.579] [exthost] [info] ExtensionService#loadCommonJSModule file:///home/ian/.vscode/extensions/equinusocio.vsc-material-theme-icons-1.1.4/out/src/extension
[2020-06-19 17:07:47.630] [exthost] [info] ExtensionService#_doActivateExtension vscode.configuration-editing {"startup":false,"extensionId":{"value":"vscode.configuration-editing","_lower":"vscode.configuration-editing"},"activationEvent":"onLanguage:json"}
[2020-06-19 17:07:47.630] [exthost] [info] ExtensionService#loadCommonJSModule file:///var/lib/snapd/snap/code/35/usr/share/code/resources/app/extensions/configuration-editing/dist/extension
[2020-06-19 17:07:47.648] [exthost] [info] ExtensionService#_doActivateExtension vscode.extension-editing {"startup":false,"extensionId":{"value":"vscode.extension-editing","_lower":"vscode.extension-editing"},"activationEvent":"onLanguage:json"}
[2020-06-19 17:07:47.648] [exthost] [info] ExtensionService#loadCommonJSModule file:///var/lib/snapd/snap/code/35/usr/share/code/resources/app/extensions/extension-editing/dist/extension
[2020-06-19 17:07:47.694] [exthost] [info] ExtensionService#_doActivateExtension vscode.json-language-features {"startup":false,"extensionId":{"value":"vscode.json-language-features","_lower":"vscode.json-language-features"},"activationEvent":"onLanguage:json"}
[2020-06-19 17:07:47.694] [exthost] [info] ExtensionService#loadCommonJSModule file:///var/lib/snapd/snap/code/35/usr/share/code/resources/app/extensions/json-language-features/client/dist/jsonMain
[2020-06-19 17:07:47.748] [exthost] [info] ExtensionService#_doActivateExtension ms-vscode.js-debug {"startup":false,"extensionId":{"value":"ms-vscode.js-debug","_lower":"ms-vscode.js-debug"},"activationEvent":"onLanguage:json"}
[2020-06-19 17:07:47.748] [exthost] [info] ExtensionService#loadCommonJSModule file:///var/lib/snapd/snap/code/35/usr/share/code/resources/app/extensions/ms-vscode.js-debug/src/extension.js
[2020-06-19 17:07:48.234] [exthost] [info] ExtensionService#_doActivateExtension vscode.npm {"startup":false,"extensionId":{"value":"vscode.npm","_lower":"vscode.npm"},"activationEvent":"onLanguage:json"}
[2020-06-19 17:07:48.235] [exthost] [info] ExtensionService#loadCommonJSModule file:///var/lib/snapd/snap/code/35/usr/share/code/resources/app/extensions/npm/dist/main
[2020-06-19 17:07:48.263] [exthost] [info] ExtensionService#_doActivateExtension vscode.typescript-language-features {"startup":false,"extensionId":{"value":"vscode.typescript-language-features","_lower":"vscode.typescript-language-features"},"activationEvent":"onLanguage:typescript"}
[2020-06-19 17:07:48.263] [exthost] [info] ExtensionService#loadCommonJSModule file:///var/lib/snapd/snap/code/35/usr/share/code/resources/app/extensions/typescript-language-features/dist/extension
[2020-06-19 17:07:48.326] [exthost] [info] ExtensionService#_doActivateExtension VisualStudioExptTeam.vscodeintellicode {"startup":false,"extensionId":{"value":"VisualStudioExptTeam.vscodeintellicode","_lower":"visualstudioexptteam.vscodeintellicode"},"activationEvent":"onLanguage:typescript"}
[2020-06-19 17:07:48.326] [exthost] [info] ExtensionService#loadCommonJSModule file:///home/ian/.vscode/extensions/visualstudioexptteam.vscodeintellicode-1.2.8/dist/intellicode
[2020-06-19 17:07:48.472] [exthost] [info] ExtensionService#_doActivateExtension vscode.css-language-features {"startup":false,"extensionId":{"value":"vscode.css-language-features","_lower":"vscode.css-language-features"},"activationEvent":"onLanguage:css"}
[2020-06-19 17:07:48.473] [exthost] [info] ExtensionService#loadCommonJSModule file:///var/lib/snapd/snap/code/35/usr/share/code/resources/app/extensions/css-language-features/client/dist/node/cssClientMain
[2020-06-19 17:07:49.390] [exthost] [info] ExtensionService#_doActivateExtension vscode.github {"startup":true,"extensionId":{"value":"vscode.github","_lower":"vscode.github"},"activationEvent":"*"}
[2020-06-19 17:07:49.390] [exthost] [info] ExtensionService#loadCommonJSModule file:///var/lib/snapd/snap/code/35/usr/share/code/resources/app/extensions/github/dist/extension.js
[2020-06-19 17:07:49.485] [exthost] [info] eager extensions activated
```

What is the problem and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

This might be a version problem, you could try reinstalling an older version of the Python extension.
Right Click at Python in extension and try to install another one.

Comment: I didn't understand what happened, but now, extension have installed. I did nothing. Thanks for your time.